# ADO.NET data services or Entity framework - Which one to learn?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I am having a bit of a free time and i am planning to catch up on some new technology. I started of my .NET development career as a ASP.NET developer. Presently I am done with ASP.NET development,for that matter i am done with any front end development. These days i am into Business layer and DAL development with the primary focus on WCF service development and I am going to continue doing so. Given the situation which one would be helpful for me in moving forward? ADO.NET data services or Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3):

Those are two totally separate items:

- **ADO.NET Entity Framework** is a data-access and data-modelling technology to handle database storage, modelling objects etc. on top of that
- **ADO.NET Data Services** is a REST-ful way of exposing such data models to a wide audience, by means of browsers and URLs

So basically, first you need to know a bit about Entity Framework, and then you should learn how to make that available to the world at large.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

[ADO.NET Entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) and [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx) are different

Comment: Data Services are based on EF models, so not *that* different.

Comment: Aren't data services based on IUpdateable and IQueryable and not 100% tied to EF?